# Is it possible to launch a facebook app to be used only by some users

Tags: facebook, login-control

Basically I want to create a game, but I want it to be played only by the students of my university. They should log in with their facebook account with the means provided by facebook and then put their student id and a password to play the game. Is this permitted by facebook or the game must be open to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can choose to allow or deny entrance into an app/game based on if they are part of a university network. There is no requirement that an app make itself available for everyone.